# Preserve content-type when using Copy Activity to Unzip .zip Files in ADFv2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using Azure Data Factory v2 to unzip a large .zip containing different files (.html, .css, etc) using a Copy Activity. The source and sink datasets are each a normal azure blob storage.

The issue I'm having is, that all the unzipped files have content-type "application/octet-stream" instead of "text/html" or "text/css", etc..
Since the goal is to unzip it to a static hosting blob storage the octet-stream content type prevents me from normally opening the index.html and it just downloads it for me when I try to access it. Manually changing it works, but that's not really a solution.

It seems like there should be an option in the Copy-Activity so set attributes to preserve (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-preserve-metadata) but I don't have this option in my web interface and setting it in the json also doesn't do anything - it just gets removed after saving the new json definition.

Is there any way to solve this problem with data factory tools/configuration only? Since using an additional azure function to change all the content-types again isn't a feasible option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable **Preserve** option in copy activity setting you need to select a particular file in Source to process. As you are processing Zip file it will not get enabled.

AFAIK **content-type** is a property of blob and **application/octet-stream** is by default value of it.

**The workaround is only as you suggested using an additional azure function to change all the content-types or using rest api to set the properties of blob.**

- Using [Rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-properties?tabs=azure-ad) you can set the properties of blob storge.
- Using an additional azure function to change all the content-types.

You can use it from ADF. First you need to get list of all files from get metadata.
[image]
Then pass these values in foreach loop.
[image]
Under foreach activity with help of switch condition based on filename or extension, you could change content-type of it with azure function or rest Api.
[image]
Above condition will execute first case if file filename contain `html` ,second condition if filename contain `css` and so on as per your need under each condition you need to execute appropriate function or rest api.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. May have to scrap the whole idea using adfv2 if I have to use some outside function anyway but I really appreciate the extensive answer and possible solutions!